# Same bundle identifier for OS X application and Preferences

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am developing an OS X application. For my app, there is a preference extension. I am trying to save all the preferences settings values of the application by using `[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]`. In order to read the settings values from my application, can I use same bundle identifier for the preferences application and Cocoa application and Preference pane application?

Answer (score 2):

That's not recommended--the bundle identifier is not just for preferences. Each bundle should have a unique identifier. However, it's easy to use a custom `NSUserDefaults` to share some preferences (or all) between two bundles:

```
NSUserDefaults* defaults = [NSUserDefaults new];
[defaults addSuiteNamed:@"com.yourCompany.someSharedIdentifier"];
```

Simply use this object instead of `standardUserDefaults` for any preferences you wish for your two bundles to share.